# weighted RNG speed problem in C++

Tags: c++, random, performance, weighting

Edit: to clarify, the problem is with the **second** algorithm.

I have a bit of C++ code that samples cards from a 52 card deck, which works just fine:

```
void sample_allcards(int table[5], int holes[], int players) {
    int temp[5 + 2 * players];
    bool try_again;
    int c, n, i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5 + 2 * players; i++) {
        try_again = true;
        while (try_again == true) {
            try_again = false;
            c = fast_rand52();
            // reject collisions
            for (n = 0; n < i + 1; n++) {
                try_again = (temp[n] == c) || try_again;
            }
            temp[i] = c;
        }
    }
    copy_cards(table, temp, 5);
    copy_cards(holes, temp + 5, 2 * players);
}
```

I am implementing code to sample the hole cards according to a known distribution (stored as a 2d table). My code for this looks like:

```
void sample_allcards_weighted(double weights[][HOLE_CARDS], int table[5], int holes[], int players) {
    // weights are distribution over hole cards
    int temp[5 + 2 * players];
    int n, i;

    // table cards
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        bool try_again = true;
        while (try_again == true) {
            try_again = false;
            int c = fast_rand52();
            // reject collisions
            for (n = 0; n < i + 1; n++) {
                try_again = (temp[n] == c) || try_again;
            }
            temp[i] = c;
        }
    }

    for (int player = 0; player < players; player++) {
        // hole cards according to distribution
        i = 5 + 2 * player;
        bool try_again = true;
        while (try_again == true) {
            try_again = false;
            // weighted-sample c1 and c2 at once
            // h is a number < 1325
            int h = weighted_randi(&weights[player][0], HOLE_CARDS);
            // i2h uses h and sets temp[i] to the 2 cards implied by h
            i2h(&temp[i], h);
            // reject collisions
            for (n = 0; n < i; n++) {
                try_again = (temp[n] == temp[i]) || (temp[n] == temp[i+1]) || try_again;
            }
        }
    }

    copy_cards(table, temp, 5);
    copy_cards(holes, temp + 5, 2 * players);
}
```

My problem? The weighted sampling algorithm is a factor of 10 slower. Speed is very important for my application.

Is there a way to improve the speed of my algorithm to something more reasonable? Am I doing something wrong in my implementation?

Thanks.

edit: I was asked about this function, which I should have posted, since it is key

```
inline int weighted_randi(double *w, int num_choices) {
double r = fast_randd();
double threshold = 0;
int n;

for (n = 0; n < num_choices; n++) {
    threshold += *w;
    if (r <= threshold) return n;
    w++;
}
// shouldn't get this far
cerr << n << "\t" << threshold << "\t" << r << endl;
assert(n < num_choices);
return -1;
```

}

...and i2h() is basically just an array lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reject collisions are turning an *O*(n) algorithm into (I think) an *O*(n^2) operation.

There are two ways to select cards from a deck: shuffle and pop, or pick sets until the elements of the set are unique; you are doing the latter which requires a considerable amount of backtracking.

I didn't look at the details of the code, just a quick scan.

Comment: Indeed, `std::random_shuffle` should be both simpler and unbiased (as far as the underlying random number generator - `rand() % x` by default? - is unbiased).

Comment: Thanks; this is a good observation of the first algo. I may well incorporate your insight. However it totally avoids the question; how do I weight the selection of cards?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm using a Mersenne twister RNG, not rand(), but I could implement my own shuffle of course.

Comment: Using random_shuffle resulted in a ~30% improvement for the uniformly sampled code (the first routine).

Answer (score 1):

you could gain some speed by replacing the all the loops that check if a card is taken with a bit mask, eg for a pool of 52 cards, we prevent collisions like so:

```
DWORD dwMask[2] = {0}; //64 bits
//...
int nCard;
while(true)
{
    nCard = rand_52();
    if(!(dwMask[nCard >> 5] & 1 << (nCard & 31)))
    {
        dwMask[nCard >> 5] |= 1 << (nCard & 31);
        break;
    }
}
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the memcpy(1326*sizeof(double)) within the retry-loop.  It doesn't seem to change, so should it be copied each time?

Comment: Good spot, thanks, not sure how I missed that. I just tried moving it out of the loop, it didn't help much.

Comment: Did you move it out of both nested loops (for and while) or is that not possible?

Comment: I eliminated the memcpy by doing simply
int h = weighted_randi(&weights[player][0], HOLE_CARDS);

Comment: Too bad that didn't make a difference (but it did simplify the code a bit).  My best bet would be to also hava a look at weighted_randi() and i2h().  When nothing apparent can be changed, measure (profiling or as suggested by Mike)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than tell you what the problem is, let me suggest how you can find it. Either 1) single-step it in the IDE, or 2) [randomly halt it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) to see what it's doing.

That said, sampling by rejection, as you are doing, can take an unreasonably long time if you are rejecting most samples.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner "try_again" for loop should stop as soon as it sets try_again to true - there's no point in doing more work after you know you need to try again.

```
for (n = 0; n < i && !try_again; n++) {
    try_again = (temp[n] == temp[i]) || (temp[n] == temp[i+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the second question about picking from a weighted set also has an algorithmic replacement that should be less time complex. This is based on the principle of that which is pre-computed does not need to be re-computed.

In an ordinary selection, you have an integral number of bins which makes picking a bin an *O*(1) operation. Your `weighted_randi` function has bins of real length, thus selection in your current version operates in *O*(n) time. Since you don't say (but do imply) that the vector of weights `w` is constant, I'll assume that it is.

You aren't interested in the width of the bins, *per se*, you are interested in the locations of their edges that you re-compute on every call to `weighted_randi` using the variable `threshold`. If the constancy of `w` is true, pre-computing a list of edges (that is, the value of `threshold` for all `*w`) is your *O*(n) step which need only be done once. If you put the results in a (naturally) ordered list, a binary search on all future calls yields an *O*(log n) time complexity with an increase in space needed of only `sizeof w / sizeof w[0]`.